# Disable directon aware hover on mobile

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to disable the direction aware hover effect when browsing my website on mobile devices and just display an overlay div with like 30% of the image height. Here is the effect that I am using http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/09/direction-aware-hover-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs this, I fixed it by adding a window width check when the page is loaded. It doesn't work on page resize though. Hover Effect works only if the window width is above 768px.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            if($(window).width() > 768){
                $(function() {

                $(' #da-thumbs > div > div > li ').each( function() { $(this).hoverdir(); } );

        });
        }
    });
```